# Disable other row table when one is clicked in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html-table, row

I have following table:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="p in value" ng-click="lista.select(p)" ng-class="{'selected':p.selected}" >
    <td >{{p.id_patient.id_patient}}</td>
    <td>{{p.id_priority.priority_name}}</td>
    <td>{{p.status_name}}</td>
    <td>{{p.id_typology.examination_name}}  </td>
    <td>{{p.data_inserimento.$date}}</td>
 </tr>
```

I want to disable all other rows when one is clicked. I tried to add a `ng-disabled="p.selected"` but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: You also need a reference to check if there's a selected value. `ng-disabled="hasSelected() && !p.selected"`. When you say `disable` you might want to apply a different class don't you?

Comment: Currently, there is nothing to "disable"  you are just binding data to table cells.  You need some sort of input field to disable.  I'm not sure what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Instead of setting a flag on the selected value, store the selected value in the scope (or the controller): Then you can use something like `ng-class="{selected: p === theSelectedValue, disabled: p !== theSelectedValue}`.

Comment: what you can do on a tr td value, it is already disabled. what you want to achieve?

Comment: I would like to disable all rows except the selected one

Comment: @taguenizy not necessarily, the important is that the other rows are not clicclable. Wath hasSelected() do?

Comment: wath I can not understand is why if I add ng-disabled="true" to my <tr> tag not works.

Comment: `ng-disable` works for `button` and  `input` for instance. You could add an expression to `ng-click` so it only performs the action when possible. Like  `ng-click= expression && lista.select(p)` if expression = `true` then it performs `lista.select(p)`, otherwise it does nothing.